esbuild not tree-shaking aws-sdk comand injected client
When bundling typescript code with esBuild, having this configuration:
const buildOpts: BuildOptions = {
  target: 'es2020',
  format: 'esm',
  mainFields: ['module', 'main'],
  metafile: true,
  treeShaking: true,
};

moduleResolution: Bundler in tsconfig
With this sample code
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const s3Client = new S3Client();

console.log(s3Client.config);

In the resulting bundle, I would expect only to have S3Client-related code, but it also contains all S3 commands, because of command injection library does.
I would expect that setting mainFields to module, main, would prevent esBuild from adding to the bundle files that are not imported, as I do not have import { S3 } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
Am I missing something in the setup, or it is just how esBuild works?

I am not too familiar with 'tree-shaking', but did you try adding treeShaking: 'ignore-annotations', to your build ?

treeShaking accepts only boolean
